# Is it possible to use vscode snippets with CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, boilerplate

I'm looking to make a CSS boilerplate if possible, using the snippet function on vscode. I've been looking on youtube for advice on snippets and most people talk about it with JavaScript in mind. Snippets is a new syntax that I'm not familiar with and having looked at the documentation, I'm still not clear how to use it with other languages. There is an option to create a CSS snippet, but it opens in json just the same.

Can anyone offer any advice here?

Many thanks

Comment: you can write snippets for any language, specific or a snippet for all languages, if the snippet syntax is to complex for you don't start programming

Answer (score 1):

I'm also kinda new with snippets and emmets, I don't really know the difference, but I could wrap it off just enough so it worked for me. Hope this helps you too.

```
"todo":{
        "prefix": "todo",
        "body": ":root{\n\n    $1\n$1\n\n}\n\nhtml{\n    font-size: 62.5%;\n}\nbody{\n    font-size: 16px;\n}\n*{\n    margin: 0;\n    text-decoration: none;\n}\n\n/*****************************INICIO*****************************/\n\n$2\n$2\n$3"
    }
```

You just have to write the name of your emmet between quotation marks, after that write a colon and open your Brackets.

On the prefix part, you need to write the word that's gonna make your emmet appear. You could have an emmet named "main syntax" and your prefix could be simply "main" so when you write main the emmet is gonna appear.

The body part is where you write the thing that your emmet is gonna write for you each time you use it. You write it once so you don't have to write it over and over. :D

The syntax here is pretty easy to understand:

- \n is gonna make your text appear on the next line.
- $ when you use this symbol what you make is that you can write in its space. You need to write a number after the symbol $1, $2, $3...
  You can add one wherever you want. If you add multiple $1 all the spaces where you wrote it are gonna write the same text. When you press the tab button you change from the $1 to the $2 and from the $2 to the $3

I modified the emmet that I regularly use so you can see what I'm talking about.

- The rest is just the text or code you use.

You need to paste the code in the css.json file. To get to this file you need to go to open the command palette then write ">user" and select "Preferences: Configure User Snippets", after you click that look for the "css.json" option. Finally, paste the code between the brackets.

If you want to add a new emmet after the previous one just add a comma after your emmet bracket and start writing your new emmet, that's it. :)